# Convert data.frame wide to long while concatenating date formats

Tags: r, matrix, frame

In R (or other language), I want to transform an upper data frame to lower one.
How can I do that?
Thank you beforehand.

```
year month income expense
2016 07 50 15
2016 08 30 75


month income_expense
1 2016-07             50
2 2016-07            -15
3 2016-08             30
4 2016-08            -75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that you are trying to do multiple operations in the same question: combine dates columns, melt your data, some colnames transformations and sorting

This will give your expected output:

```
library(tidyr); library(reshape2); library(dplyr)
df %>% unite("date", c(year, month)) %>% 
  mutate(expense=-expense) %>% melt(value.name="income_expense") %>% 
  select(-variable) %>% arrange(date)
####      date income_expense
#### 1 2016_07             50
#### 2 2016_07            -15
#### 3 2016_08             30
#### 4 2016_08            -75
```

I'm using three different libraries here, for better readability of the code. It might be possible to do it with base R, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using only two packages, `dplyr` and `tidyr`

First, your dataset:

```
df <- dplyr::data_frame(
  year =2016,
  month = c("07", "08"),
  income = c(50,30), 
  expense = c(15, 75)
)
```

The `mutate()` function  in `dplyr` creates/edits individual variables. The `gather()` function in `tidyr` will bring multiple variables/columns together in the way that you specify.

```
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    month = paste0(year, "-", month)
  ) %>% 
  tidyr::gather(
    key = direction, #your name for the new column containing classification 'key' 
    value = income_expense, #your name for the new column containing values
    income:expense #which columns you're acting on
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(income_expense =  
    ifelse(direction=='expense', -income_expense, income_expense)  
  )
```

The output has all the information you'd need (but we will clean it up in the last step)

```
   > df
# A tibble: 4 × 4
   year   month direction income_expense
  <dbl>   <chr>     <chr>          <dbl>
1  2016 2016-07    income             50
2  2016 2016-08    income             30
3  2016 2016-07   expense            -15
4  2016 2016-08   expense            -75
```

Finally, we `select()` to drop columns we don't want, and then arrange it so that `df` shows the rows in the same order as you described in the question.

```
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::select(-year, -direction) %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(month)
> df
# A tibble: 4 × 2
    month income_expense
    <chr>          <dbl>
1 2016-07             50
2 2016-07            -15
3 2016-08             30
4 2016-08            -75
```

NB: I guess that I'm using three libraries, including `magrittr` for the pipe operator `%>%`. But, since the pipe operator is the best thing ever, I often forget to count `magrittr`.

Comment: since you like so much the pipe operator :-), you'll probably be enchanted to discover the "pipe assignment" operator. Instead of writing `df <- df %>% ...` you can simply write `df %<>% ...`

Comment: Great point! Although I tend not to use it because I like seeing the difference between assignment `<-` and piping `%>%`. I am afraid that I'll mix up the pipe and the pipe assignment operator as they're very similar to the eye.

Comment: ok so you're familiar with it already. Partly true what you say, i agree, probably not ideal for a SO answer.